# Routes collision in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am working on a project using Laravel 4, I have a "user route" to show user profiles by their username:

```
Route::get("user/{username}", array( 'as' => 'userProfile', 'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile') );
```

But here I have another route which shows a user's messages.

```
Route::get('user/messages', array( 'as' => 'userMessages', 'uses' => 'MessageController@getMessages') )
```

But there is a collision here. Laravel thinks "messages" is a username because of first Route.

How can I work around this? Could some one help me, thanks.

Comment: I'd try switching their order.

Comment: it worked, but what if a username is really "messages" !! it does not make scenes but how Laravel handle these cases ?

Comment: @aliA it will still open the messages page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the order of these Routes as Laravel processes them in the order they are defined in `routes.php`

so,

```
Route::get('user/messages', array( 'as' => 'userMessages', 'uses' => 'MessageController@getMessages') )
```

comes before

```
Route::get("user/{username}", array( 'as' => 'userProfile', 'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile') );
```

And then in your `User` validation you must prevent anyone from choosing the username `messages`