# Laravel Route Is not working because of Generic route

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel and learning just basic stuff. I am trying to create a new Route to create a user into database. So I created a Route like this -

```
Route::get('users/"create"', 'PagesController@create');
```

But I also have one Route for users trying to access their profile-

```
Route::get('users/{username}', 'PagesController@show');
```

Now when I try to access users/create it redirect me to show method instead of create method in controller. I am guessing this is because of generic nature of users/{username}. So my question is how to deal with such situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Routes collision in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314710/routes-collision-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Word "collision" did't come to my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order that you define routes is important. If you define your routes like this - in this order, it will work.

```
Route::get('users/create', 'PagesController@create'); 
Route::get('users/{username}', 'PagesController@show');
```

Note - I noticed you used `'users/"create"'` - that is an error - it should be `'users/create'` like in my example.

p.s. make sure you dont allow a user with the username called 'create' - or they will never be able to get to their profile page.

Comment: Thanks Its working. But out of curiosity is there any other way to fix such errors. As it is pointed out in another post what if username is message?

Comment: Yes - use a different route - like `users/show/{username}`